# Dhtmlx scheduler in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using dhtmlx scheduler in my MVC project. My problem is i need to block the previous days in the scheduler. For example today is Monday means the previous day before monday should be blocked. Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance..

I added my code below.

```
 public ActionResult CalendarView( int id , tblUser user )
        {


                string val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserTypeId"];
                int code = Convert.ToInt32(val);
                Session["Butype"] = val;

                var cal = (from s
                            in db.tblUsers
                           where s.UserTypeId == code && s.UserID == id
                           select new Appt
                           {

                               BusinessName = s.tblBusinessCategory.BusinessName,
                               StartTime = s.WorkingHour.StartTime

                           }).FirstOrDefault();
                Session["BUName"] = cal.BusinessName.ToString();
var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this);
                scheduler.Skin = DHXScheduler.Skins.Flat;
                scheduler.Data.Loader.PreventCache();
                scheduler.EnableDynamicLoading(SchedulerDataLoader.DynamicalLoadingMode.Week);
                scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.Recurring);
                //scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.ActiveLinks);

                //scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.Collision);

                //scheduler.Extensions.Add(SchedulerExtensions.Extension.Limit);
                scheduler.LoadData = true;
                scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = true;
                scheduler.Config.show_loading = true;
                //  scheduler.BeforeInit.Add("schedulerClient.init()");
                Session["BUId"] = id;
                var parameter = new SqlParameter[1];
                parameter[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "UserId", Value = id };
                List<Appt> cm = new List<Appt>();
                using (SYTEntities context = new SYTEntities())
                {
                    cm = context.Database.SqlQuery<Appt>("exec spHoliday @UserId", parameter).ToList();

                }
                int iyear = 2015;
                int imonth = 8;
                int iday = 09;


                foreach (var cp in cm)
                {
                    iyear = cp.HolidayDate.Year;
                    imonth = cp.HolidayDate.Month;
                    iday = cp.HolidayDate.Day;

                    scheduler.TimeSpans.Add(new DHXMarkTime()
                    {

                        StartDate = new DateTime(iyear, imonth, iday),       //new DateTime(2015, 8, 06), //hl.HolidayDate ?? default(DateTime),    
                        EndDate = new DateTime(iyear, imonth, iday + 1),
                        //  Day = DayOfWeek.Friday,

                        CssClass = "red_section",
                        HTML = "hos",
                        SpanType = DHXTimeSpan.Type.BlockEvents
                    });
                }

    scheduler.BeforeInit.Add("schedulerClient.init()");

                return View(scheduler);


        }
```